# Treeview font color of the node is shown in blue color always in my asp.net(C# 4.0) page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, treeview

I have added one TreeView control in my ASP.NET page.when i seeing the aspx file, it's forecolor is set to black color.But when i seeing in the browser then it is changed to blue color by default.

i want to display tree node forecolor in black color only...

This is my Code...

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ImageSet="Arrows" 
                                    ExpandDepth="0" ShowCheckBoxes="None" onselectednodechanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged" 
                                    style="margin-left: 5px" Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="Black" NodeWrap="True" 
                                    Height="250px" NodeStyle-CssClass="Color" Width="275px" Font-Size="X-Small" >
                                </asp:TreeView>
```

Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tree1" runat="server">
            <Nodes>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="A"></asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="B"></asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="C"></asp:TreeNode>
            </Nodes>
            <NodeStyle CssClass="Color" />
        </asp:TreeView>



<style type="text/css">
        .Color{
            color:black !important;
        }
    </style>
```

Thanks

Comment: @Saravanan can you please paste some code? In my PC its working fine.

Comment: @Dev... Now it is working... thanks a lot... i missed !important in CSS.. What does it means for?

Comment: @Saravanan OK. It means that CSS property must be applied to the element. Please mark as selected and upvote if it has satisfied your requirement :)

Comment: I did already :-) can you tell me what does it meant for !important in CSS?

Comment: @Saravanan It means that CSS property must be applied to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Whenever you add the node named childNode, you have to set the property called SelectAction as given below

`childNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;`

By default the SelectAction will be select, because of that you will getting the hyperlink that is blue colour to your text.

If your adding those elements in static do it this way

```
<Nodes>


 <asp:TreeNode Text="Node1" SelectAction="None"></asp:TreeNode>

</Nodes>
```

Hope it helps!!!